# Consulta Laravel con parámetros que pueden ser null

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

Quiero hacer una consulta a una base de datos mediante un filtro, pero los campos de filtración no son obligatorios. Quiero que al dejar un campo de filtro vacío la consulta entienda que no tiene que poner ninguna restricción en ese campo. De esta forma si el usuario dejara todos los campos vacíos la aplicación devolvería la base de datos completa.

Probé con este código pero no funciona si se dejan los primeros campos vacíos, ya que devuelve 0 registros pese a que debería devolver más:

```
            $clientes = Cliente::where("nombre", "LIKE", "%$request->name%")->where("tipo", "LIKE", "%$request->type%")->where("ubicacion", "LIKE", "%$request->ubication%")->get();
```

Probé también este otro código, pero por alguna razón muchas veces me devuelve 0 registros pese a que no debería:

```
    // Con este if establezco cual es el primer filtro para declarar la variable $clientes 
    if($request->name != null){
        $clientes = Cliente::where("nombre", "LIKE", "%$request->name%");
    }else if($request->type != null){
        $clientes = Cliente::where("tipo", "LIKE", "%$request->type%");
    }else if($request->product != null){
        $clientes = Cliente::where("producto", "LIKE", "%$request->product%");
    }else if($request->ubication != null){
        $clientes = Cliente::where("ubcacion", "LIKE", "%$request->ubication%");
    }else{
        $clientes = Cliente::all();
    }

    // Con estos otros establezco las siguientes restricciones dependiendo de que campos fueron llenados
    if($request->type != null) $clientes = $clientes->where("tipo", "LIKE", "%$request->type%");
    if($request->product != null) $clientes = $clientes->where("tipo", "LIKE", "%$request->product%");
    if($request->ubication != null) $clientes = $clientes->where("tipo", "LIKE", "%$request->ubication%");


    // dd($clientes->get());
    return view('home', ["clientes"=>$clientes]);
```

Comment: Es preferible tener una sola varibale para los filtros,es decir $request->filtersLIke y ahi tengas cada una de las columnas a filtrary solo tienes que hacer un for con las varibales existentes

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo que utilices local scopes. Crea uno por cada filtro que necesites y dentro de la logica de cada uno verifica si el parámetro suministrado es null, si es asi, no agregas ningun where adicional a la consulta. El scope para el nombre por ejemplo, seria:

```
public function scopewhereName($query, $name)
    {
        if (!is_null($name)) {
            return $query->where('nombre', 'LIKE', '%'.$name.'%');
        }
        return $query;
    }
```

Teniendo todos los scopes necesarios, tu controlador deberia tener algo como:

```
$clientes = Cliente::whereName($request->name)
                   ->whereType($request->type)
                   ->whereUbication($request->ubication)
                   ->get();
```

Puedes ver mas sobre los scopes en https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#local-scopes